# Get data from different model odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

Is it possible in one tree view load data from eg. (Project Task, Project Issue, Purchase Order) where create date = Today.

Example:

[image: Example]

Any simple solution?

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Comment: @Pointer Do you want find all data created by day in tree view

Comment: @KHELILIHamza  The best solution is in tree view display name, date and maybe module name, after click go to form of that module.

Comment: @VikiChavada   Example: https://postimg.org/image/eaq5d53qt/

Comment: @Pointer I think you can achieve this refer Cherif Odoo code of onscreen report kind of thing and also you can add a button to open that particular record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, return all from database:

In .py file add below code:

```py
class CustomReport(models.Model):
    _name = "my.report"
    _description = "my report"
    _auto = False


    name = fields.Char(string='Name', readonly=True)

    def init(self, cr):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        cr.execute("""CREATE or REPLACE VIEW my_report as 
                        SELECT
                        id,
                        concat(name,' | ', description) as name
                        from project_task 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 
                        id,
                        concat(name,' | ', amount_total) as name
                        from purchase_order
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 
                        id,
                        concat(number,' | ', residual) as name 
                        from account_invoice
                        """)
```

In .xml file add:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_my_report_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">my.report.tree</field>
        <field name="model">my.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <graph string="Name" type="bar">
                <field name="id" type="row" />
                <field name="name" type="row" />
            </graph>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record id="action_my_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Name</field>
        <field name="res_model">my.report</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="My report" action="action_my_report" id="menu_my_report"/>

</odoo>
```

Resault:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want always to show the records that there create date is today you can do this.

1- first in backend to use tree view or any view you should create one and only one model for it.

2- when you need to show more then one model in the same tree view or as we can say you want to show a result of a query.

3- create a model that create a view in database instead of a table means the model is extracting
            data from the view (query) in database .

Example: see module `\addons\account\report\account_invoice_report.py`

To prevent the model from creating a table in database.

```py
    _name = 'view.name'
    _auto = False
```

Then to create the view overrid the method :

```py
    # in odoo 10.0
    @api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        # drop the view first 
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self.env.cr, self._table)

        # create the view.
        self.env.cr.execute("""CREATE or REPLACE VIEW %s as (
          you query here.
        )""" % self._table)
```

and now the the model will extract data from the view hope this is what yo want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load data from one single `Model` then you can use action domain to filter.

If you want to load data from three different model where their `create_date` is today, you can make one simple model for example `view_mod` and put there all the interesting fields you want to view and then for each model you should create their corresponding `view_mod` record and then again you need to filter with action domain to see all the `view_mod` records created today

Comment: Tnx for answer, any online example?